# Как правильно задать transition?

Tags: html, css, transition

Подскажите, как задать transition так, чтобы зелёное меню плавно выплывало влево?
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="numbersTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="inpCell"><input type="number" id="jopa" class="outputPanel" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="number">7</td>
                    <td class="number">8</td>
                    <td class="number">9</td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="tableCell"><table class="operTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>DEL</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&divide;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&times;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>+</td>
                </tr>
                </table></td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="greenStringCell"><div class="greenString">
                    <table>
                        
                    </table>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">4</td>
                <td class="number">5</td>
                <td class="number">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">1</td>
                <td class="number">2</td>
                <td class="number">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">,</td>
                <td class="number">0</td>
                <td class="equal">=</td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 570px;
    width: 288px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.numbersTable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: sans serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
}

.outputPanel {
    font-size: 43px;
    height: 145px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: none;
    -webkit-writing-mode: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    
}
td {
    border: 0px solid black;
}
tr {
    border: 0px solid black;
}

.inpCell {
    height: 145px;
}
.operTable {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 160, 0.8);
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.tableCell {
    width: 20%;
}
.greenStringCell {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100%;
}
.greenString {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(30, 255, 137, 1);
}
.active {
    /*height: 425px;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 216px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .2s;
*/}
.greenString:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    height: 425px;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 216px;
}
```

Comment: Сдвигая остальные или поверх них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В transition лучше задать к какому именно свойству применяется (transition: width 0.2s). Все свойства которые не должны изменяться при наведении должны быть заданы в .greenString, в :hover меняется только ширина.

```
.greenString {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgba(30, 255, 137, 1);
    transition: width 0.2s;
    height: 425px;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
}
.greenString:hover {
    width: 216px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Доработал Ваш код

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 570px;
    width: 288px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.numbersTable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: sans serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
}

.outputPanel {
    font-size: 43px;
    height: 145px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: none;
    -webkit-writing-mode: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    
}
td {
    border: 0px solid black;
}
tr {
    border: 0px solid black;
}

.inpCell {
    height: 145px;
}
.operTable {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 160, 0.8);
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.tableCell {
    width: 20%;
}
.greenStringCell {
    height: 100%;
}
.greenString {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(30, 255, 137, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.greenString:hover {
    width: 60px;
    transition: width .3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="numbersTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="inpCell"><input type="number" id="jopa" class="outputPanel" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="number">7</td>
                    <td class="number">8</td>
                    <td class="number">9</td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="tableCell"><table class="operTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>DEL</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&divide;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&times;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>+</td>
                </tr>
                </table></td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="greenStringCell"><div class="greenString">
                    <table>
                        
                    </table>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">4</td>
                <td class="number">5</td>
                <td class="number">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">1</td>
                <td class="number">2</td>
                <td class="number">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="number">,</td>
                <td class="number">0</td>
                <td class="equal">=</td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```